Shading color not rendering correctly
The following code is given:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{grad}{100bp}{
    color(0bp)=(blue);
    color(100bp)=(red)
}


\begin{document}

\tikz{
\draw[ shading=grad,line width=0] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
\draw[ left color=blue,right color =red,line width=0] (0,3) rectangle ++(3,3);
}

\end{document}

which yields the following output

while I expected this:

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

This phenomenon is explained in this comment by @Qrrbrbirlbel

The problem here is that the area between 0bp and 25bp as well as between 75bp and 100bp will not be visisble: The shading is scaled and translated such that …. You need color(0bp)=(c1); color(25bp)=(c1); color(75bp)=(c2); color(100bp)=(c2);. TikZ's shadings are actually adding color(50bp)=(c3); where c3 is c1!50!c2.

So for your code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{grad}{100bp}{
    color(0bp)=(blue);
    color(25bp)=(blue);
    color(75bp)=(red);
    color(100bp)=(red)
}


\begin{document}

\tikz{
\draw[ shading=grad,line width=0] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
\draw[ left color=blue,right color =red,line width=0] (0,3) rectangle ++(3,3);
}

\end{document}



Thank you. Does it hold for any number of shading stops? For example, for a shading (red,0bp)(green,50bp)(blue,100bp) should it be (red,0bp)(red,25bp)(green,50bp)(blue,75bp)(blue,100bp)? And that what's special about 25bp and what happens there?

@KeenTeen The number of colour stops does not matter.

@KeenTeen See https://tikz.dev/base-shadings#pgf.back/pgfshadepath for some explanation where the numbers come from
